# Change the color of the points in labelled plot

Tags: gnuplot

The script works, without any change in color, however:

```
plot '_numXY' using 2:3:(sprintf('%d', $1)) \
    with labels offset 0,1 point pointtype 6 ps 2 notitle lc rgb "blue"
```

The points are *black*. I want to see the points in *blue* color.
Why does `lc rgb "blue"` not work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `lc` settings are ignored for the `labels` plotting style if they don't follow immediately the `point` option. In your case you must only place the `notitle` at the end.

```
plot '_numXY' using 2:3:(sprintf('%d', $1)) \
    with labels offset 0,1 point pointtype 6 ps 2 lc rgb "blue" notitle
```

As a demonstration example:

```
set samples 11
set xrange [0:10]
plot '+' using 1:1:(sprintf('%d', $1)) \
    with labels offset 0,1 point pointtype 6 ps 2 lc rgb "blue" notitle
```

The result with 4.6.5 is:

[image]